# How to remove intermediate class after serialize to XML and provide specific structured XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have class like mention below:

```
public class Employee
    {

        public Address x;


        public Contact  y;
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Address1;
        public string Address2;
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string EmailID;
        public string PhoneNumber;
    }
```

Output: I need below XML structure after serialize it using C#.

```
<Employee>
  <Address1>
    India
  </Address1>

  <Address2>
GUjarat
  </Address2>

  <EmailID>
abc@gmail.com  
  </EmailID>

  <PhoneNumber>
046094609
  </PhoneNumber>

</Employee>
```

I want to change something in class like set XML property to class property.

Comment: Was Marc's answer helpful for you, Ronak? Please try to acknowledge assistance you receive, just as you would when people help you outside of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that xml from those classes using `XmlSerializer`. You will need to flatten your data (perhaps just for the serialization) to something that has the addresses and contact emails as members of the same type. For example:

```
[XmlRoot("Employee")]
public class EmployeeDTO {
    public string Address1 {get;set;}
    public string Address2 {get;set;}
    public string EmailID {get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

The other option is to do it manually via DOM manipulation (`XDocument` / `XmlDocument`) or the writer API (`XmlWriter`).

---

Edit: actually you *can* kinda do it, but it is horrible:

```
public class Employee
{

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Address x;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Contact  y;

    public string Address1 {
        get { return x == null ? null : x.Address1; }
        set { (x ?? (x = new Address()).Address1 = value; }
    }
    // note null handling in the above
    // TODO: the others
}
```

Please don't do this.